# How to use MyBatis mappers in Spring's JUnit tests?

Tags: spring, junit, mockito, mybatis, spring-test

For tests I use:

- Spring Test 3.2.3.RELEASE
- JUnit 4.12
- Mockito 1.10.19

The following test code should save some entity into the database, however, this does not occur:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ControllerTestConfig.class})
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    SomeMapper someMapper;

    @Test
    public void shouldCreateSomeEntity() {
        SomeEntity someEntity = new SomeEntity();
        someEntity.setSomeProperty("property");
        ...

        someMapper.createSomeEntity(someEntity);
    }

    ...
}
```

I use a simulated implementation of the mapper:

```
@Configuration
public class ControllerTestConfig {

    @Bean
    public SomeMapper SomeMapper() {
        return Mockito.mock(SomeMapper.class);
    }

    ...
}
```

Because the implementation is simulated, the method call is intercepted in the class `org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.MethodInterceptorFilter`.

The mapper is an interface:

```
public interface SomeMapper {

    @Insert("Insert into some_table (id, some_entity_id, type, full_name) values (#{id}, #{someEntityId}, #{type}, #{fullName})")
    @SelectKey(statement="select nextval('seqid_static_data');", keyProperty="id", before=true, resultType=long.class)
    void createSomeEntity(SomeEntity someEntity);

    ...
}
```

Thus, it is not possible to create an instance of this mapper. For example, by this way:

```
@Bean
public SomeMapper SomeMapper() {
    return new SomeMapper();
}

...
```

How to use MyBatis mappers in Spring's JUnit tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to emulate method call by `doAnswer` or `doThrow`, they should works with **void** methods. For example:

```
@Test
public void shouldCreateSomeEntity() {
    SomeEntity someEntity = new SomeEntity();
    someEntity.setSomeProperty("property");       

    Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> {
           invocation.getArgument(0).setSomeProperty("changed_property")
        }).when(someMapper).createSomeEntity(Mockito.eq(someEntity));

    someMapper.createSomeEntity(someEntity);
    Assert.assertEquals("changed_property", someEntity.getSomeProperty());
}
```